# Continuous solutions to a first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Im giving the pde as follows

$(x+y) \partial _x u+(y-x)\partial_y u=0$.

First I need to show that a continuous solution must be constant and then deduce that the difference of any two continuous solutions to the inhomogenous pde

$
(x+y) \partial _x u+(y-x)\partial_y u=f(x.y)$
$

only differ by a constant. And last find the unique solution to the pde with f(x,y)=y and ivc $u(0,0)=0$.

First I tried to find the characteristic curves by solving $ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-x}{x+y}$. But I cant solves this ode hence I cant really get anywhere with this exercise.

Any help?

Comment: Do change of variable $y(t)=tx(t)$ to solve the ode.